# How can I display a native iOS/Android UI control/element in an HTML5 app? LinkedIn does this

Tags: html, cross-platform, cordova, native

LinkedIn says the following about their new high-performance mobile app: “There’s this battle between HTML5 web apps and native apps. But **we’ve interspersed HTML5 in the native app, where web-based content excels**. The things that are hard to do in HTML5 are a scrolling infinite list, so we went native with that.”' via [How LinkedIn used Node.js and HTML5 to build a better, faster app](http://venturebeat.com/2011/08/16/linkedin-node/)

**How can I display a native iOS/Android UI control/element in an HTML5 app?**

**How can we display a scrolling infinite list in PhoneGap?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I display a native iOS/Android UI control/element in an HTML5 app?

You can't.  The quote you highlighted says "we've interspersed HTML5 in the native app", not "we've interspersed native controls in the HTML5 app". Read it again.

> How can we display a scrolling infinite list in PhoneGap?

PhoneGap just adds device APIs to a webview. It doesn't generate native controls, so you can't, not without extending PhoneGap.

Comment: OK, thank you for clarifying! If anyone sees advice on extending PhoneGap in this manner... I'd love to see it.